# Can't extract basic data using ThingspeakHTTP

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, http, iot, thingspeak

I don't know anything about HTML, but I want to extract the % probability of the Northern lights being visible from this webpage
[http://aurorawatch.ca/](http://www.aurorawatch.ca/).
I entered this into the URL field, and selected HTML version 1.

When I inspect the text element I want and copy the Xpath I get the following:

"/html/body/div[1](http://www.aurorawatch.ca/)/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[1](http://www.aurorawatch.ca/)/td/div[1](http://www.aurorawatch.ca/)/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span"

and enter this into the "parse string" field of the ThingSpeak API app, but get the following error:

"Error parsing document, try a different parse string."

Most people who get this error seem to be getting data that doesn't load with the original page, so I think I must be missing something.

If there is a better solution for pulling this number to my ESP8266 than creating a thingspeak API, I would love to hear it too!

Comment: Post your code for a better understand of question

Comment: Maybe the website is blocking thingspeak as a scraper. You would want to make the ESP8266 do the GET request and then parse the data. I'd suggest using http://www.aurorawatch.ca/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=28&Itemid=47 as it's a) less data, and b) less likely to change.

Comment: @Majenko Thanks for the quick response! That's a good suggestion, using the alternate page. I thought that was possible too, but when I leave the parser string blank, the thingspeak api request returns the full site.

I know this is beyond the scope of the question, but do you have any recommendation for where to start learning how to make the GET request I want from the ESP8266?

Comment: why do you select HTTP 1.0 (HTML 1?)

Comment: @Juraj I believe that's what version the website I'm attempting to get data from is build on

Comment: I can see no reason for it not to work. I have manually downloaded the webpage source, prettified it with xmllint, then worked through each node of the xpath, and it is exactly as it should be. Yet it can't parse it. Maybe there is something about the content that ThingSpeak's parser doesn't like.

Comment: I tested the date and it returned the logo. something is added into page with script or style?

Comment: Ok, I have it working. It doesn't like the first `tbody`. Remove that and it starts working.  Also it's good to add `/text()` to the end.  I have it parsing this page: http://www.aurorawatch.ca/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=28&Itemid=47 with this xpath: `/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/table[2]/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/text()`

Comment: just for interest:   here is another site that has aurora visibility percentages ....  https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/aurora-nowcast-map.txt

Comment: @jsotola that is where I looked first, which has a few awesome resources! The format of the text array is a little ambiguous though (is it -90deg to 90deg top to bottom, or bottom to top?), and I am lucky enough to go to the university that made Aurora watch for the city I live in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this page, since the other is the front page of the site and more likely to be dynamic:

- http://www.aurorawatch.ca/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=28&Itemid=47

The XPath is also slightly different. The first `tbody` in the reported path doesn't actually exist. You should also add `/text()` to the end of the path to just return the textual content of the node:

- `/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/table[2]/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/text()`